# jQuery Ajax returning 404 when method = post

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an ajax script that runs, it looks like this:

```
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/?page_id=104256',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { name : 'name2' },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log("Details0: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                },
            });
```

This runs fine but returns a 404 from the page set as the 'url'
If I remove 'type: post'

Comment: What is your backend ? it may be possible that the server side is not allowing post action ?

Comment: Wordpress backend. But it works fine with my other script which runs almost the exact same code. @IgorisAzanovas

Comment: Try getting post data through general <form> tag with submit button to check if all data that i'm passign is ok and it load without ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I forgot to add the name="" parameter in my input types. Doh!

Answer (score 3):

Here your method: 'Post', Type is something what you want to get in return like text

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/?page_id=104256',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { name : 'name2' },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log("Details0: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                },
            });
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately. However, removing it makes it work (but doesn't allow me to post the data).

Comment: which data you are not getting on server side?? this name : 'name2'??

Comment: That is not the problem, the problem is that it is returning an error (triggering the error function) and giving me a 404 (as though the url doesn't exist)

Comment: I am not sure about other languages but dont you think something is missing in this url?? http://localhost/?page_id=104256. can you try to hit the same url in the browser. ??

Comment: Works perfectly fine if I access the URL from the browser

Comment: I think here you no need to give absolute path. just need to use relative path. I am not sure about other languages. but if i am talking about java then i am using like this.. suppose my jsp is executeAjax.jsp and its path is localhost:8080/executeAjax.jsp then i'll use in my url as. url : 'executeAjax.jsp?page_id=104256'

Comment: It is Javascript. It shouldn't be absolute path, especially not in a parameter called 'url' but that didn't work

Comment: ohh is it .js file??. If is it so you can call it directly like  url : 'executeAjax.js'

Comment: If is it so you can call it directly like url : 'executeAjax.js'

Comment: Didn't make a difference

Comment: try to give path from root...get context path of your project suppose it is TestProject/executeAjax.js.

Comment: what was the fix !?

Answer (score 1):

If `type: 'POST'` is omitted, jQuery is treating it like a `GET` request, which it defaults to [see the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax), where the resource may not exist therefore resulting in a the `404` you're seeing.

Comment: The resource does exist. If I remove type: "post" it works fine.